# How could I record new domain names as they are registered?

Tags: registration, dns

The website [Domain Daily](http://domain-daily.com/) provides a list of new domain names.

I have a client who would like to implement similar functionality in-house, for semi-real-time tracking of new registrations, but doesn't know how to go about it.

Instinctively, I'd be thinking some sort of service interacting with DNS, WHOIS, or maybe even becoming an official domain name registrar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reliable way to do this would be to strike a deal with registrys for the TLDs you're interested in (e.g. Verisign (.com), Nominet (.co.uk) etc) and get regular copies of the zone files.  They dont tend to make this kind of thing widely avaible though!  TLDs like .aero give it away for free however.

Answer (score 1):

this works fine for gTLDs (com/net/org/...) as their zone files are public (at least for registrars). this works not at all or at least not in an easy way for most ccTLDs. there are some services that offer some degree of automation around it mainly from the perspective of domains that become available not the other way round.
"just developing something in-house" is not going to work as for the ccTLD approach you need to monitor DNS for years to get at least a somewhat meaningful base to work off.

Answer (score 0):

Check out prior to doing this if it would be legal at all. The site owner may have explicitly prohibited doing do in his terms of service.

Comment: Not really thinking in terms of scraping from domain-daily or similar sites; I'm looking for the underlying source of the data.

Comment: Scraping the details directly from the DNS or Whois is against the T&Cs (and also the database copyright) of almost every TLD.